# Assigning Arrays to different variables

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am having a simple requirement of Assigning Multiple arrays.  Right now i am doing something like.

```
   employees = Array.new
      projects = Array.new
      practices = Array.new
      entities = Array.new
      categories = Array.new
      groups = Array.new
      external_inputs = Array.new
      payrolls = Array.new
```

I Want that `employees, projects, practices, entities ...payrolls` all should be assigned to `Array.new` in a single line
Please suggest some better and clean ways of doing it.  Maybe by Metaprogramming.

Comment: starting a method setting 8 variables to an empty value looks like the start of a hell of a (imperative) time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly but fulfilling the requirements:

```
employees, projects, practices, entities, categories, groups, external_inputs, payrolls = Array.new(8) { [] }
```

Comment: Thanks i was looking for something same.

Answer (score 4):

> I Want that `employees`, `projects`, `practices`, `entities`, …, `payrolls` all should be assigned to `Array.new` in a single line

Here ya go:

```
employees = Array.new; projects = Array.new; practices = Array.new; entities = Array.new; categories = Array.new; groups = Array.new; external_inputs = Array.new; payrolls = Array.new
```

Voilà, a single line, just as you requested.

Now, why you have such a large, complex method that it needs 8 local variables is another question altogether.

Answer (score 3):

```
employees, projects, practices, entities, categories, groups, external_inputs, payrolls = 
  8.times.map { [] }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not one line, but it's a lot cleaner to use:

```
employees        = []
projects         = []
practices        = []
entities         = []
categories       = []
groups           = []
external_inputs  = []
payrolls         = []
```

But, if you want to do it more "cleverly", you could try:

```
employees = projects = practices = entities = categories = groups = external_inputs = payrolls = nil
%w(employees projects practices entities categories groups external_inputs payrolls).each {|v| eval "#{v} = []" }
```

That said, it's probably easier to just collect the values into a hash.

```
Hash[*%w(employees projects practices entities categories groups external_inputs payrolls).map {|k| [k, []] }.flatten(1)]

# Result
# {"employees"=>[], "projects"=>[], "practices"=>[], "entities"=>[], "categories"=>[], "groups"=>[], "external_inputs"=>[], "payrolls"=>[]}
```